# PyQgs: unresolved reference for QgsProject() and QgsVectorLayer()

Tags: pyqgis-3, pycharm

In my code I'm using the classes QgsProject() and QgsVectorLayer(). However PyCharm gives me the following error:

> Unresolved reference 'QgsProject' Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't.

The Project Interpreter is "Python3.7(firstplugin) C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\pyton-qgis.bat" which should be correct.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I think I need to import something but I can't find what

Comment: Show us the current `import` lines in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have imported [`QgsProject`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Project/QgsProject.html) and [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html):

```
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer)
```

Comment: yes, that was missing. Thank you :)